# How can I insert a list of videos in ionic 2?

Tags: angularjs, video, youtube, ionic2

I am coding a mobile app on ionic 2. One of the pages of my app is a news thread, in a kind of Facebook fashion, displaying some messages, photos, videos... My problem being, I can't display the videos. I've seen a lot of answers to that problem already, but it didn't work for me (they were probably solutions for ionic 1).

So, I want to display a Youtube video. I write the following code in my HTML:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let Video of VideoList">
  <video src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/{{Video.Link}}" frameborder="0" width="560" height="300"></video>
</ion-item>
```

Please note that I tried with the "iframe" tag as well, and it also doesn't work.
And in my TypeScript code:

```
VideoList: Array<any>;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public http:Http, public navParams: NavParams) {
  http.get(URL).toPromise().then((response) => {
    this.VideoList= response.json();
  });
}
```

Where `URL` is a link that I use to get a JSON array, containing the list of videos to display (as well as other stuff not relevant to my issue). For privacy reasons I just didn't want to write the real URL here.

I'm pretty sure my code is good, since it works for other kind of data, just not for videos. I guess I need to whitelist or "sanitize" those videos, but I don't manage to do that. Anyone knows how to fix my problem?

Thanks

Comment: can you post your error log?

Comment: did you tried with `[src]` ??

Comment: try to define one `baseUrl` and change like this `src={{ baseUrl + Video.Link}}`

Comment: @Fernando Del Olmo Yeah I did, didn't work though :/

Comment: @hrdkisback I don't get any error, ever. Just my videos won't display. I'll try the baseUrl thing soon and let you know if it works :)
Anyway thanks a lot for help guys! It's very much appreciated.

Comment: @hrdkisback I tried what you suggested, unfortunately my video still won't display.

Comment: @ntyss declare array like this `public VideoList: Array<{Link: string}> = [];` and then push data in to `VideoList` using loop `this.VideoList.push(response);`

Comment: @hrdkisback Thanks a lot for your answer, but it didn't work for me :/ I still have nothing displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found the soution after some time. It was actually not that hard, just need to know how to do it.
At the beginning of the TypeScript file, you need to import a "sanitizer":

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

Note that you DO NOT need to declare it as a provider in the app.module.ts file.

Though you need to add it in the constructor:

```
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer)
```

Then somewhere in your .ts file:

```
this.videoUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('https://www.youtube.com/embed/your_Youtube_key');
```

Of course you need beforehands to declare the property `videoUrl`. And then, you just need to call `videoUrl` in your html:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" [src]="videoUrl"></iframe>
```

And it works! Thanks for your help anyway guys.